# Sending formData to API in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form-data

I am using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert HTML to images.
So whenever the user submits the form, I am trying to send the image as blob and other details to the API using `formData`.
I am sending `formData` to the API to process the submitted data.
When user click on submit button, below code is responsible.

```
function handleReport(target = 'body') {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector(target))
      .then((canvas) => {
        let pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); // PNG is the default
        fetch(pngUrl)
          .then((res) => res.blob())
          .then((blob) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('images', [blob]);

            // textarea content
            formData.append('description', textAreaValue);

            // user device info
            formData.append('device[platform]', device.payload.platform);
            formData.append('device[name]', device.payload.name);
            formData.append('device[version]', device.payload.version);
            formData.append('device[ip]', device.payload.ip);
            formData.append('device[id]', device.payload.id);
            formData.append('device[app_version]', device.payload.app_version);
            formData.append('device[device_token]', device.payload.device_token);

            dispatch(actions.contactUs(util.getApiToken(), util.getToken(), formData));
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

**action definition :**

```
export function contactUs(apitoken, token, payload) {
  return {
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: `${API_ENDPOINT}/contact-us?api_token=${apitoken}`,
      headers: {
        ...AUTH_HEADERS,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: payload,
      // body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      types: [
        types.CONTACT_US_REQUEST,
        types.CONTACT_US_RECEIVE,
      ],
    },
  };
}
```

**Given below is the screenshot (not full screenshot) of payload (what user sent after clicking submit button) in Chrome browser**

[image]

**and this is the response I am getting from API**

[image]

**What is my problem !**
I am sending all required keys (refer formData) but don't why am I getting error like :

> **description field is required**

Comment: what's your tech stack on the server? how is the payload being desterilized on the server, what's the shape of the object there?

Comment: We are using LAMP stack for backend.

Comment: I want to ask you that is there any header property I am missing as I am using formData() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My header content is -

```
AUTH_HEADERS = {
  'X-Authorization': X_AUTHORIZATION,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};
```

I just resolved my issue by removing `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` which I was sending.

Now I am sending request to API without header.

```
headers: {
          'X-Authorization': X_AUTHORIZATION,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
```

Now everything is working is fine.